# Xcode not showing iOS 6 UI

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode5

I have an application build on Xcode 4.6 and iOS 6.1, but now apple requirement of submitting app must be published using Xcode 5.0. I set the deployment target to 6.1 in Xcode 5 and publish the app to app store.

I have a plan to shift completely to ios7 later but when I run app from Xcode 5 I am getting old UI but if i am downloading from store I am getting the ios7 UI which is not optimised and all loping very bad.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: run App from Xcode 5? Do you mean in iOS 7 Simulator? You can install iOS 6.1 Simulator in Xcode Preferences > Downloads

Comment: By the way, iOS 6 real devices can help you in this case too.

Comment: You need to update your app to support iOS 7.  You can no longer submit apps built against the iOS 6 SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some UI elements are iOS version depended (no matter on what Xcode version your app was compiled). If you are using iOS 7 (on the simulator or on a real device) your `UIAlertView` for example will have the new iOS 7 UI. (Blurred white with blue writing)
I'm guessing that your iPhone has iOS 7 on it while you are trying to run your app from Xcode on iOS 6 simulator.

> On a device running iOS 7, all of the system UI—such as alerts and
>   notifications—uses the iOS 7 appearance, even if your app is currently
>   using an earlier appearance.

[iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH14-SW1)

If you want to keep the legacy UI and still use Xcode 5 you can read this [great tutorial](http://jeffreysambells.com/2014/01/10/legacy-ui-with-xcode-5-and-ios-7-sdk).

I'd still advise against this, staying behind will stack more and more problems that you'll need to solve eventually.

Comment: I have iphone5 with ios7, but I did not update the UI according to ios7 like flat navigation bar or new table view. I am expecting old ios6 UI. Yes you are correct alert view and other system level UI will display accord to iOS. But I am expecting old ios6 UI in my iphone5 running ios7, because I did not update and have deployment target 6.1 in xcode5.

Comment: That's not how stuff work. I've updated my answer with more info and a link to the iOS 7 UI Transition Guide.

Comment: @Seveg I have no issues that how system UI appear, problem is I want ios6 appearance for my UI. Xcode5 entirely changed my UI to ios7 (I am not talking about system UI.)

Comment: If "Xcode changed your UI" you are on the wrong Base SDK. Read this: http://jeffreysambells.com/2014/01/10/legacy-ui-with-xcode-5-and-ios-7-sdk